# Transform two for loops method in one lambda function

Tags: python, function, lambda

I have created this 'two for loops' method in which suppose if I have tokenize a sentence to a list as [w1, w2, w3, .., wn] I want to output the following couples(NOT bigrams)

```
 for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(i+1, range(len(words))):
        couples = (words[i], words[j])
```

- w1, w2
- w1, w3
- w1, w4
- ....
- ....
- w2, w3
- w2, w4
- ....

But I want in lambda function format in order to used is in my apache spark program. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the purpose of these for loops? `couples = (words[i], words[j])` probably doesn't do what you really want.

Comment: It's really easy to turn this into a list comprehension, which you could then return from a lambda function.

Comment: Note that in python, we prefer to loop over a list directly with something like `for x in words:` rather than looping over an index like you do in many other languages.

Answer (score 5):

I would start by iterating directly over the list:

```
for x in words:
    for y in words:
        couples = x, y
```

However this gives the full Cartesian product which isn't quite the same as what you have originally. So we need the indexes for the first loop, but not for the second:

```
for i, x in enumerate(words):
    for y in words[i:]:
        couples = x, y
```

Now we can translate this into a generator expression (rather than a lambda):

```
all_couples = ((x, y) for y in words[i:] for i, x in enumerate(words))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried it to a simple tokenized list words = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'sentence'] and I got only ('sentence', 'sentence') as output..

Comment: @Er1Hall Your original question doesn't do any output.

Comment: shouldn't be `((x, y)   for i, x in enumerate(words) for y in words[i + 1:])` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using combinations from itertools will get the result you want.

```
from itertools import combinations
for tup in combinations(words, 2):
    print(tup)

('This', 'is')
('This', 'an')
('This', 'example')
('This', 'sentence')
('is', 'an')
('is', 'example')
('is', 'sentence')
('an', 'example')
('an', 'sentence')
('example', 'sentence')
```